# php multi curl take more time than usual

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl, php-curl

my Php script use curl_multi to check for Facebook tokens validation
for a long time it works perfectly

it check more than 30000 url in 60 to 70 second 
but this week i started getting 504 Gateway Time-out error

and i found that the same script check for 4000 token in more than 100 second now and i can't check for all my tokens in one time because after 100 second the website give me the 504 error

any solution or is this problem from Facebook-graph-api ?

thanks

Comment: Maybe they blocked the requests due to spam. Mostly you can try it again in a few hours, but they also can block your host/IP for scanning their service.